# How to calculate normal vector of a SCNPlane?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

Goal: Define the normal vector for a plane represented by `SCNPlane`.

As mentioned in Apple's documentation [Working with Vectors - Calculate the Normal of a Triangle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/working_with_vectors), I can calculate the normal vector based on 3 points from the plane. The issue here is that I don't know how I can get 3 points that they make proper triangle. I've noticed that `SCNPlane` has a property `boundingBox` and it can represent 2 of the triangle vertices (`min` and `max`). How can I find the 3rd vertex that is placed on the `SCNPlane`? I cannot use the center of the `SCNPlane`, because it creates a line along with `min` and `max` points from `boundingBox`.

Is there any other way that can help me to retrieve a normal vector for the `SCNPlane`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnplane) we learn that

> The surface is one-sided. Its surface normal vectors point in the positive z-axis direction of its local coordinate space, so it is only visible from that direction by default.

The normal of a `SCNPlane` is always `(0, 0, 1)` in local space and that cannot change.

When it is attached to a node, the orientation of that node determines the normal in an another coordinate system. You can use [`simdConvertVector:toNode:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881850-simdconvertvector) to convert between coordinate spaces:

```swift
// normal expressed in world space
let normal = simd_normalize(node.simdConvertVector(simd_float3(0, 0, 1), to: nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer, in order to retrieve the points that define the plane, you can query the plane's geometry sources.

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 100, height: 20)
print("Sources for normal: \(vertices(sources: plane.sources(for: .normal)))")
print("Sources for vertex: \(vertices(sources: plane.sources(for: .vertex)))")

extension UnsafeRawPointer {
    func loadUnaligned<T>(as: T.Type, count: Int) -> [T] {
        assert(_isPOD(T.self)) // relies on the type being POD (no refcounting or other management)
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: count)
        defer { buffer.deallocate() }
        memcpy(buffer, self, MemoryLayout<T>.size * count)
        return (0..<count).map({ index in buffer.advanced(by: index).pointee })
    }
}

func vertices(sources: [SCNGeometrySource]) -> [[SCNVector3]] {

    var result = [[SCNVector3]]()
    result.reserveCapacity(sources.count)
    for source in sources {
        precondition(source.usesFloatComponents == true, "SCNVector3 can handle only three-component vectors whose components are floating-point values, i.e., floats or doubles")
        precondition(source.componentsPerVector == 3, "SCNVector3 can only be used for three components per vector")
        
        let shouldUseFloatNotDouble: Bool
        if source.bytesPerComponent == 4 {
            shouldUseFloatNotDouble = true
        }
        else if source.bytesPerComponent == 8 {
            shouldUseFloatNotDouble = false
        }
        else {
            assert(false, "The SCNGeometrySource has reported an unexpected byte size for its vector components, not 4 bytes (float) or 8 bytes (double) but \(source.bytesPerComponent). I am not equipped for this so I am going to use floats and hope for the best. This will probably not work. Sorry.")
            shouldUseFloatNotDouble = true
        }
        
        let vectors = source.data.withUnsafeBytes {
            (p: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> [SCNVector3] in
            if (shouldUseFloatNotDouble) {
                let simdArray = (p.baseAddress! + source.dataOffset).loadUnaligned(as: SIMD3<Float>.self, count: source.vectorCount)
                return simdArray.map { simd in SCNVector3(simd)}
            } else {
                let simdArray = (p.baseAddress! + source.dataOffset).loadUnaligned(as: SIMD3<Double>.self, count: source.vectorCount)
                return simdArray.map { simd in SCNVector3(simd)}
            }
        }
        result.append(vectors)
    }
    return result
}
```

Output:

```
Sources for normal: [[__C.SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1.0), __C.SCNVector3(x: 1.0, y: 0.5, z: -0.5), __C.SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1.0), __C.SCNVector3(x: 1.0, y: -0.5, z: 0.5)]]
Sources for vertex: [[__C.SCNVector3(x: -0.5, y: -0.5, z: 0.0), __C.SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0), __C.SCNVector3(x: 0.5, y: -0.5, z: 0.0), __C.SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0)]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, especially as it targets my question about finding 3 points on the plane. This looks very good, but I have few more questions. What are the vertices for the .normal semantic? I tried to visualize them and can't figure it out. I changed the size of the plane and the 3 points from .vertex are outside the plane. Why? And last question, how it works? Do you have any sources that I can find for a detailed explanation?

Comment: Although they are outside of the plane bounds, they might still define the plane as such, which should be sufficient to calculate the normal. My answer is based mostly on intuition, I scanned documentation and googled any material on geometry sources, but couldn't find anything that answers your questions.